# Powerline git status

Tags: git, python-2.7

So I'm setting up the new version of [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) status bar and wanted to integrate the [VCS segment](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/segments/common.html#module-powerline.segments.common.vcs) in my shell.

Now I have it set up correctly by include this line my shell default.json.

```
        {
            "function": "powerline.segments.common.vcs.branch",
            "priority": 10,
            "args": {
                "status_colors": true
            }
        }
```

But when I attempt to open a git repo, I get a huge error before it starts to work.

```
2014-10-06 10:42 Python[5530] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
```

I checked the powerline issues and could find anything relating to this. Anyone have any experience with powerline have any idea whats going on?

Comment: did you able to fix it?

Comment: Ah, totally forgot about this. Yes, it seems to be an issue on OSX
https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/osx.html#i-receive-fseventstreamstart-register-with-server-error-with-status-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is an issue on OSX. Basically it occurs when you try to watch too many files.

[Here's the explanation](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/osx.html#i-receive-fseventstreamstart-register-with-server-error-with-status-colors) from the powerline docs